# What is the deal with Type Script <>

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

This syntax is from the Angular2 Hero tutorial.

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> == getHeroes(): (Promise: Hero[]) ?
```

I am confused about the `Promise<Hero[]>` part, in particular. Is it a way to represent multiple types at a time? What does the area between the `<` and `>` represent?

I am new to TypeScript and Angular2, but I want to know.

Comment: I guess you mean https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

< SomeType > is a generic type in Typescript which means you can have a Class or Function with SubType of T and you can do anything to it without knowing its actual type in the function definition.

For example:

```
  DoSomething<T> (input : T) : T {
      // doing something on input 
      input += 2;
      // return something with <T> type
      return input;
  }
```

see [the Typescript handbook on generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's how generics are specified. A Promise can return a value of some type. The stuff inside the `<>` specifies what this specific promise will return. You can get some more information here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html